# Push notification through Appcelerator not delivered to the iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator's cloud services to send push notifications.
I'm sending notifications from both their web admin console as well as using their REST API. 2 iOS devices successfully subscribed, and i sent them notifications, but the devices never get the notification.
All ceritificate and provisions on Apple's dashboard seems correct. all Appcelerator's cloud responses seem successful, but still the notifications never display on the devices.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sending the push to the Development or Production push server?

Comment: You are asking about Appcelerator's part or Apple's? I'm using the Appcelerator's Production Key.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Appcelerator, but one of the most common causes for pushes not being delivered is when the message is sent to the Apple Production server, but the app has been signed with a Developer certificate (which will cause it to register with the Apple Developer server)